# Echo a php output within a Javascript code

Tags: javascript, php, html

I couldn't get the code below to display the success word, any idea what's the problem with the code below?

Thanks in advance.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function verification(){

    var s = document.test_form.textfield.value;

    if (s == "") {
        alert("Please enter a value");
        return false;
    } else {
        <?php echo "sucess"; ?>
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to wrap your echo in an alert

```
alert("<?php echo 'sucess'; ?>")
```

Answer (score 2):

Your output in javascript is:

```
else {
    sucess
}
```

What this mean? Try something like this if you want to force output by `PHP`:

```
else {
    <?php echo "alert('success');"; ?>
}
```

Or just return `true` to confirm submitting the form:

```
else {
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do 2 things:

```
console.log("<?php echo 'success'; ?>"); // Will display a message into JS console
```

or:

```
alert("<?php echo 'success'; ?>"); // Will display a message into JS alert box
```

In your code, you only writing 'success' inside the javascript code, and when the browser will try to execute this JS code, it will not understand 'success'and it will throw an error.

Comment: I was actually editing while you typed your message :) Thx anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the text on your page, you can use inside a `document.write`:

```
document.write("<?php echo "success"; ?>");
```

Otherwise, you can use an `alert()` or `console.log()`

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('body').innerHTML('<?php echo 'sucess'; ?>');
```

assuming that your body tag has the id body(`<body id="body">`)

EDIT. of course you can do that with every tag that has an id.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting PHP to write Javascript you might want to think about using a templating engine like Smarty or Twig.

Answer (score 0):

**For the case the file is a Javascript**
If the original file is an external `.js` (not a `.php`) and is being read on the client side (browser) then it simply does not know how to parse PHP.

Therefore when the browser gets to:

```
} else {
    <?php echo "sucess"; ?>
}
```

It simply does not recognize the `<?php` and thus is throwing an error.

Replace the PHP string by `alert("success")` or, if you do want to query the server and have the server output something [take a look into Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

**For the case the file is a PHP and the Javascript code is embedded in the html**
Replace the code by

```
} else {
    <?php echo 'alert("sucess";)' ?>
}
```